# printing just numbers from a string

Tags: python, function

I am trying to print out just the numbers from a string. For some reason the output is a little off.

```
def get_numerals(string):
    for i in string:
        if i in "1234567890":
            print(i,end="")
        else:
            print("",end = "")
    return i

print(get_numerals("CS1301"))
print(get_numerals("Georgia Institute of Technology"))
print(get_numerals("8675309"))
```

output:

```
13011
y
86753099
```

Comment: You are always returning the last character of the string.

Comment: how can I fix this? I am trying to keep this code as basic as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic way is :

```
def get_numerals(string):
    tempstr =""
    for i in string:
       
        if i.isdigit():
            tempstr=tempstr+i
       
    return tempstr

print(get_numerals("CS1301"))
print(get_numerals("Georgia Institute of Technology"))
print(get_numerals("8675309"))
```

output:

```
1301

8675309
```

using `Regular expression` you can also get digit from a string

```
import re

def get_numerals(string):
    temp = re.findall(r'\d+', string) 
    res = list(map(int, temp)) 
    
    return res
    
print(get_numerals("CS1301"))
print(get_numerals("Georgia Institute of Technology"))
print(get_numerals("8675309"))
```

output :

```
[1301]
[]
[8675309]
```

Comment: thank you for the response, however I am trying to keep this code as basic as possible (it is for learning purposes). I have removed the return i and am one step closer. now I get the correct input but of course get a bunch of "none" statements in addition.

Comment: Thank you very much, I greatly appreciate it. I forgot about establishing a value for a variable and adding to it.

Answer (score 3):

```
def get_numerals(string):
    return ''.join( [x for x in string if x.isdigit() ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

you are returning the last character no matter it is digits or character. A simple workaround from your version is:

```
def get_numerals(string):
    for i in string:
        if i.isdigit():  # isdigit() is more convenient to check whether the char is digit or not
            print(i, end="")
        else:
            print("", end = "")
    return ''

print(get_numerals("CS1301"))  # 1301
print(get_numerals("Georgia Institute of Technology")) # 
print(get_numerals("8675309")) # 8675309
```

or you can use regex:

```
import re   
def get_numerals(string):
    res = re.findall(r'\d+', string)  # finds positive digits
    # res = re.findall(r'-?\d+', string) # if you want negative and positive digts
    return "".join(res)


print(get_numerals("CS13011111"))  # 1301
print(get_numerals("Georgia Institute of Technology")) # 
print(get_numerals("8675309")) # 8675309
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_numerals(string):
   return ''.join(filter(lambda i: i.isdigit(), string)) 
    
print(get_numerals("CS1301"))
print(get_numerals("Georgia Institute of Technology"))
print(get_numerals("8675309"))
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).